# How can I make my input field tags validate like Gmail ? With the help of CSS

Tags: css, validation, input

I want to make Gmail Style Input Tags background change for email address input validation with CSS, as the tag's background colour turns red for invalid input & turns green for a valid input (like *example@gmail.com*).

I have tried

````html
<input class="form-control form-control-sm mailfield" type="email" data-role="tagsinput" data-class="label-info" placeholder="Sender Mail Id" autocomplete="on" autofocus="" required="">

```css
<style> 
.bootstrap-tagsinput .tag input:valid {
    background-color:green
}

.bootstrap-tagsinput .tag input:invalid{ 
    background-color:red
}
</style>
````

Comment: Please add some code example to show people what you have tried to do.

Comment: .bootstrap-tagsinput .tag input:valid { background-color:green } .bootstrap-tagsinput .tag input:invalid{ background-color:red }

Comment: Is that the whole of your code ? You are talking about a form and some sort of validation in your question

Comment: @giuseppedeponte no it's just CSS.

Comment: <div class="form-group"><input class="form-control form-control-sm mailfield" type="email" data-role="tagsinput" data-class="label-info" placeholder="Sender Mail Id" autocomplete="on" autofocus="" required="">



<style>
.bootstrap-tagsinput .tag input:valid {
  background-color:green;
}
.bootstrap-tagsinput .tag input:invalid {
  background-color: red;
}

</style>

Comment: Aaahh, just CSS except some HTML

Comment: You should [edit](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58463404/gmail-style-input-tag-background-change-validation-css?noredirect=1#) your question

Comment: @giuseppedeponte kindly check-out my edit of question

Answer (score 0):

Your code seems to work, only you were missing trailing semicolons on your CSS property declarations, e.g.

```
    background-color: green;
```

Here is a working example:

```css
.bootstrap-tagsinput .tag input:valid {
  background-color: green;
}

.bootstrap-tagsinput .tag input:invalid {
  background-color: red;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/twitter-bootstrap/2.3.2/css/bootstrap-combined.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />

<div class="bootstrap-tagsinput">
  <label class="tag">
    <input class="form-control form-control-sm mailfield" type="email" data-role="tagsinput" data-class="label-info" placeholder="Sender Mail Id" autocomplete="on" autofocus="" required="" value="invalid-email">
  </label>
  <label class="tag">
    <input class="form-control form-control-sm mailfield" type="email" data-role="tagsinput" data-class="label-info" placeholder="Sender Mail Id" autocomplete="on" autofocus="" required="" value="valid@ema.il">
  </label>
</div>
```

Comment: This is the snippet try it and kindly help me to validate it the tags.
https://tags.bss.design/

Comment: Your CSS styling is working on your page, only the `type="email"` fields are hidden with a `display: none` property. Since the bootstrap plugin replaces the real input with its custom elements, you can no longer rely on the browser validation but implement some JS validation logic yourself.